# Difference between linking library directory and archive

Tags: c++, bazel, glfw

That question was probably asked dozens of times but I can't really find a relevant answer.

I'm trying to create a simple project using Bazel. The project includes GLFW library. Unfortunately, I can't link the project correctly. Right now Bazel produces following command for linker.

```
ld ... -lc++ -S bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/orbit/main.o lib/GLFW/libglfw3.a -lglfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework Foundation
```

For some reasons, although the library is included, linker responds with

```
ld: library not found for -lglfw3
```

But if instead of linking the library archive, I would just use its directory, it works and compiles well.

```
 ld ... -lc++ -S bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/orbit/main.o -L/Users/mightykho/Stuff/cpp/orbit/lib/GLFW -lglfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework Foundation
```

Can you please explain to me why does it make a difference and how to achieve the same results with linking just the archive?

Comment: If you put the library's binary in a location that your linker does not search it won't find it automatically unless you tell the linker where to look. In your second example you told it where to look in that non-standard location `-L/Users/mightykho/Stuff/cpp/orbit/lib/GLFW`

Comment: Hmm, thanks! I can't get my head about one thing though. So if I mistype the archive path in the original example, the linker would through an error because it can't find library archive.
Lets say I change it to lib/GLFW/libglfw4.a